# How to decode method return data into JSON object?

Tags: web3js

So, I'm trying to get the raw response of a contract method into a JSON object, and I was figuring there'd be a clever way to do it, given that I've already specified the ABI which defines the structure of the data returned by the method.

```
function getGenesByKittyID(kittyID) {
    var contractAddress = '0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d'
    var contractABI = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_interfaceID","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"cfoAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_preferredTransport","type":"string"}],"name":"tokenMetadata","outputs":[{"name":"infoUrl","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"promoCreatedCount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"ceoAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"GEN0_STARTING_PRICE","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"name":"setSiringAuctionAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"pregnantKitties","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"isPregnant","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"GEN0_AUCTION_DURATION","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"siringAuction","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"name":"setGeneScienceAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newCEO","type":"address"}],"name":"setCEO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newCOO","type":"address"}],"name":"setCOO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_startingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_endingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_duration","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createSaleAuction","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"sireAllowedToAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"canBreedWith","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"kittyIndexToApproved","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_startingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_endingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_duration","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createSiringAuction","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setAutoBirthFee","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"},{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approveSiring","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newCFO","type":"address"}],"name":"setCFO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_genes","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"createPromoKitty","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"secs","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setSecondsPerBlock","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawBalance","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"GEN0_CREATION_LIMIT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"newContractAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"name":"setSaleAuctionAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_v2Address","type":"address"}],"name":"setNewAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"secondsPerBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"tokensOfOwner","outputs":[{"name":"ownerTokens","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"giveBirth","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawAuctionBalances","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"cooldowns","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"kittyIndexToOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"cooAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"autoBirthFee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"erc721Metadata","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_genes","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createGen0Auction","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"isReadyToBreed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PROMO_CREATION_LIMIT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_contractAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setMetadataAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"saleAuction","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_id","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getKitty","outputs":[{"name":"isGestating","type":"bool"},{"name":"isReady","type":"bool"},{"name":"cooldownIndex","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nextActionAt","type":"uint256"},{"name":"siringWithId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"birthTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"matronId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sireId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"generation","type":"uint256"},{"name":"genes","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"bidOnSiringAuction","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"gen0CreatedCount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"geneScience","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"breedWithAuto","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"matronId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sireId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"cooldownEndBlock","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Pregnant","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"kittyId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"matronId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sireId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"genes","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Birth","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newContract","type":"address"}],"name":"ContractUpgrade","type":"event"}]');
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress);
    var callData = contract.getKitty.getData(kittyID);
    var result = web3.eth.call({
        to: contractAddress,
        data: callData
    }, 'latest');
    console.log(result);
}

getGenesByKittyID(8917);
```

Which gives the string:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004792ea0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a1ba7080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001fc400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020a1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d00005a169218c60b9297a52901463218c463108180d02ccb9118667a5e87358b
```

Instead of formatting it as an object with fields like:

```
{isGestating bool, isReady bool, cooldownIndex uint256, nextActionAt uint256, siringWithId uint256, birthTime uint256, matronId uint256, sireId uint256, generation uint256, genes uint256}
```

I've gotta be missing something obvious, but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: The return value is encoded using the ABI specification https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a complete working script:**

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io')

function getGenesByKittyID(kittyID) {
    var contractAddress = '0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d'
    var contractABI = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_interfaceID","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"cfoAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_preferredTransport","type":"string"}],"name":"tokenMetadata","outputs":[{"name":"infoUrl","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"promoCreatedCount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"ceoAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"GEN0_STARTING_PRICE","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"name":"setSiringAuctionAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"pregnantKitties","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"isPregnant","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"GEN0_AUCTION_DURATION","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"siringAuction","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"name":"setGeneScienceAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newCEO","type":"address"}],"name":"setCEO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newCOO","type":"address"}],"name":"setCOO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_startingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_endingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_duration","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createSaleAuction","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"sireAllowedToAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"canBreedWith","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"kittyIndexToApproved","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_startingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_endingPrice","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_duration","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createSiringAuction","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setAutoBirthFee","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"},{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approveSiring","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newCFO","type":"address"}],"name":"setCFO","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_genes","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"createPromoKitty","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"secs","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setSecondsPerBlock","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawBalance","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"GEN0_CREATION_LIMIT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"newContractAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_address","type":"address"}],"name":"setSaleAuctionAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_v2Address","type":"address"}],"name":"setNewAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"secondsPerBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"tokensOfOwner","outputs":[{"name":"ownerTokens","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"giveBirth","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawAuctionBalances","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"cooldowns","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"kittyIndexToOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"cooAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"autoBirthFee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"erc721Metadata","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_genes","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createGen0Auction","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_kittyId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"isReadyToBreed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PROMO_CREATION_LIMIT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_contractAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setMetadataAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"saleAuction","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_id","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getKitty","outputs":[{"name":"isGestating","type":"bool"},{"name":"isReady","type":"bool"},{"name":"cooldownIndex","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nextActionAt","type":"uint256"},{"name":"siringWithId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"birthTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"matronId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sireId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"generation","type":"uint256"},{"name":"genes","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"bidOnSiringAuction","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"gen0CreatedCount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"geneScience","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_matronId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_sireId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"breedWithAuto","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"matronId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sireId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"cooldownEndBlock","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Pregnant","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"kittyId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"matronId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sireId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"genes","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Birth","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newContract","type":"address"}],"name":"ContractUpgrade","type":"event"}]')
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)
    var callData = contract.methods.getKitty(kittyID).call()
    callData.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    })
}

getGenesByKittyID(8917)
```

1. Start by adding the **web3** object, connected to a blockchain provider *(in this case **[Infura](https://infura.io/)**)*. You can connect to your `localhost` if you run your own **[geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/)** node.
2. The latest version of the **[Web3.js](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html)** api uses the following syntax to **[connect to a contract](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract).**

   > var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)
3. And calls it as such *(the response is a Promise)*:

   > var callData = contract.methods.getKitty(kittyID).call()

**Output Result:**

```
{
    '0': false,
    '1': true,
    '2': '13',
    '3': '4690666',
    '4': '0',
    '5': '1511761672',
    '6': '8132',
    '7': '8353',
    '8': '13',
    '9': '621765675823685383537778066585008430767408983835250322267958849644737931',
    isGestating: false,
    isReady: true,
    cooldownIndex: '13',
    nextActionAt: '4690666',
    siringWithId: '0',
    birthTime: '1511761672',
    matronId: '8132',
    sireId: '8353',
    generation: '13',
    genes: '621765675823685383537778066585008430767408983835250322267958849644737931'
}
```